# Which would be cost effective, a display with graphics controller or without graphics controller?

Tags: stm32, graphics

I am working on a touch screen display on stm32.

I found some evaluation boards like [mikromedia-7-stm32f7](https://www.mikroe.com/mikromedia-7-stm32f7) and
[stm32h753i-eval](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-eval-boards/stm32h753i-eval.html)

Mikroelectronica uses the external controller SSD1963, although the MCU has a built in LCD-TFT controller.

Why do they use the external graphics controller SSD1963?

Comment: Combining two things into one usually saves time and money compared to having those two things separate, but "cost-effective" is a rather more subjective term and depends what your design goals are.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the same even if the name is similar. Consider why SSDxx has 80+ pins. This controller adds framebuffer and requires another controller in the TFT display (which will control the pixels). Some controllers have both in one chip like ILI9341 which has 1278 pins instead :)

STM32 TFT_LCD controller just unloads the work from the core when sending RGB data from the framebuffer to the controller. You can use it even if your controller has one, or save the memory and send actual draw data to the controller.